# PHP session variable's value in 1st page not updating to value of session variable in 2nd page after 2nd GET request

Tags: javascript, php

I am using session variables in PHP. I am making an ajax request from *modifyDetails.php* to another php file named *getDetails.php* using :

xmlhttp.open("GET", "getDetails.php?val=" + str, true);

I am trying to change the values of form fields based on the selection made in dropdown list. I am getting it correct when I make a selection for the first time
but when i make a different selection now , the values are still the same.
I have checked the values of session variable *$_SESSION['Member_details']*  in *getDetails.php* and it's values are perfectly fine but the session variable in
*modifyDetails.php* is not updating it's value.

> "modifyDetails.php"

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   $fid = $_SESSION['fid_value'];  
   $get_Member_details = $_SESSION['Member_details'];
?>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Modify Details</title>
<script src="/prj/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function fillData(str)
{  
   $(document).ready(function() 
   {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
      else{
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("kk").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "getDetails.php?val=" + str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();

      //window.alert(str); 
      var jage= "<?php echo $get_Member_details['age'];?> ";
      var jsex= "<?php echo $get_Member_details['sex'];?> ";
      var jdob= "<?php echo $get_Member_details['dob'];?> ";
      //alert(jdob);
      var jrelation = "<?php echo $get_Member_details['Relationship'];?> ";
      var jcontact = "<?php echo $get_Member_details['contact'];?> ";
      var jaddress = "<?php echo $get_Member_details['address'];?> ";
      var jpin = "<?php echo $get_Member_details['pin'];?> ";

      document.getElementById("Age").value = jage;
      //document.getElementById("Sex").value = jsex;
      document.getElementById("Dob").value = jdob;
      document.getElementById("Rel").value = jrelation;
      document.getElementById("Contact").value = jcontact;
      document.getElementById("Address").value = jaddress;
      document.getElementById("Pin").value = jpin;
   });
}
</script>
<style>
   body{
   background-color:lightgrey;
}
#button {
    background-color: green;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 2px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table { padding:2px 6px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Customer Form </h1>
    <h3>Please fill in the details below:</h3>
      <form action="modified.php" method="post">
         <table style="width:24%;">
            <tr><td>Family ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="fid" value="<?php echo "$fid";?>" readonly /></td></tr><tr></tr>
            <tr><td>Name:</td>
            <td>
              <?php
                 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
                 mysql_select_db('project');

                 $sql_query = "SELECT name FROM family WHERE fid=$fid";
                 $records = mysql_query($sql_query);

                 echo"<select name='member_name' onchange='fillData(this.value)'>";         
                 while( $family_member = mysql_fetch_array($records) ) 
                 {
                    echo "<option value='".$family_member['name']."' >".$family_member['name']."</option>";                        
                 }
                 echo "</select></td></tr>"; 

              ?> 
        <div id="kk">
        </div>
            <tr><td>Age:</td><td><input id="Age" type="text" name="age" required /></td></tr><tr></tr>
            <tr><td>Sex:</td><td><input id="Sex" type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" required />Male 
                                 <input id="Sex" type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" required/>Female</td></tr><tr></tr>
            <tr><td>Date of Birth:</td><td><input id="Dob" type="text" name="dob" required /></td></tr><tr></tr>
            <tr><td>Relationship:</td><td><input id="Rel" type="text" name="relation" list="relations" required>
                         <datalist id="relations">
                                <option value="Son">Son</option>
                                <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                                <option value="Father">Father</option>
                                <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
                                <option value="GrandMother">GrandMother</option>
                                <option value="GrandFather">GrandFather</option></td></tr><tr></tr>
                         </datalist></td></tr>  
            <tr><td>Contact Number:</td><td><input id="Contact" type="text" name="contact" required /></td></tr><tr></tr>
            <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input id="Address" type="text" name="address" required /></td></tr><tr></tr>
            <tr><td>Pincode:</td><td><input id="Pin" type="text" name="pin" required /></td></tr><tr></tr> 
         </table>  <br> 

        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>

      <br><br><br>
      <a href="search.html"> <h4>Back to Search Page</h4></a>

</body>
```

> "getDetails.php"

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   $fid =$_SESSION['fid_value']; 
?>  

<?php
 $name=$_GET['val'];
 echo $name;
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 mysql_select_db('project');

 $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM family WHERE fid=$fid AND name='$name'";
 $records = mysql_query($sql_query);

 $_SESSION['Member_details'] = mysql_fetch_array($records);

 $hold = $_SESSION['Member_details'];

 //echo $hold['dob'];
 //echo $hold['contact'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax call happens after page load, you JS is getting rendered when the session is in State 'A'.

Once you make your Ajax call, it`s in sate 'B', but at that point call to Session has already been made and the initial view is already rendered.

So, to fix the situation you should pass variables that are changing through Ajax reposne with JSON for example.